# Duality and Euler paths in graphs

Tags: graph-theory, duality

I'm computer scientist and in one of my researches I'm facing this question:
if I have a planar graph that admits an Euler path (i.e. has 0 or 2 odd degree vertices, as Euler's theorem says), then his dual graph also admits an Euler path? And its opposite: if I have a graph that doesn't admits an Euler path, then its dual also doesn't?

This is important because the algorithms that I use to create dual graphs are very computationally costly, so it takes a long time just to check the Euler paths in a graph and in its dual.

I'll be thankful if you can guide me to an answer or even a textbook/paper so I can read about it!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all as you may know, the dual of a planar graph is not unique and relates to the embedding of the graph. So we talk about an embedding of a graph.

This graph is an easy contradiction of the first part. $G$ is eulerian but $dual(G)$ is not. because it has four vertices of degree 3.

[image: A eulerian graph, which its dual isn't eulerian.]

For the second question, take $H = dual(G)$. Then $H$ is not eulerian, but $dual(H) = dual(dual(G) = G$ is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer my friend! Is there a way or rule to "predict" what graphs can produce at least one eulerian dual graph or it can be answered only by drawing each one individually?

Comment: You're welcome. I don't know the details of algorithms for drawing a planar graph. Most of them decompose the graph into 3-connected parts and draw 3-connected planar graphs. It's an interesting question. Maybe you can find your answer somewhere like: https://cs.brown.edu/~rt/gdhandbook/

Comment: @misc Bipartite planar graphs have eulerian duals.